# Checking for equivalent expression

Tags: javascript, string

I am writing JavaScript code in which the user is required to do physics calculation and enter an answer. The code should check if the answer is right or not. For example, if the correct answer is "5 N", the code should label all of these as correct answers: "5.0 N", "5.00 Newton", "5.0000 Newtons", "5 newton", "5   newtons", etc. Is there any good way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Sure there is depending on how you want this to function, what have you tried so far? For example, you could split the string by spaces and parse the first part as a number and check if the second part starts with the letter "N" (*uppercased string*). That said there are betters ways to do this without having to rely on parsing units.

Comment: Assuming this is a webpage and a test: make two inputs: an `<input type="number">` for the number and an `<input type="text">` for the unit. Parse the number as a number and display an error if it’s unparseable rather than marking it wrong. If it’s obvious what the unit is and you’re really testing the calculations, don’t even have the second textbox and just give a label of “newtons” or `<abbr title="newtons">N</abbr>`.

Comment: `parseFloat( "5.00 Newton" ) == 5` to get you started

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will try parseFloat to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Regular Expressions for this so that casing/spacing/ect can be made to not matter or matter strongly where necessary.

https://regex101.com

Comment: Thank you, I will look at the website.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this will be to put constraints on the answer in the question, e.g.

> Give the answer rounded to x places

or

> round to appropriate significant figures.

After all, as this is a physics test, sig figs are important.  Then, all you would need to do is decide what range for error is acceptable.  As for the units, again as this is physics and units are quite important, state in the questions

> Give your answer in appropriate S.I. units

or whatever is right for the question.

As for the checking, regex is probably the way to go.  You can use basic arithmetic operators for questions with simple answers or where units are in a field separate from the value.

Comment: Thank you. I considered that, but for my application, a single input for number and units will be more appropriate.